# Is a police escort (SPU) in Somaliland assigned to the foreigner automatically or must the foreigner request it?

Tags: safety, officials, somaliland, somalia

I have read that a police escort  from the elite Special Police Unit (SPU) is required in Somaliland  when traveling outside of Hargeisa. E.g. https://www.onceinalifetimejourney.com/reviews/everything-else/safety-in-somaliland-is-somaliland-safe-to-visit/#Police_escort_in_Somaliland:

> One of the most unique parts of traveling in Somaliland is the mandatory police escort all visitors outside of Hargeisa get.

Is a police escort in Somaliland assigned to the foreigner automatically or must the foreigner request it? If automatically, how does the law enforcement become aware the foreigner needs a police escort? If not automatically, how does the foreigner request the  police escort?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [Lonely Planet](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/somaliland/zeila/practical-information/directory/dangers-and-annoyances/a/nar/1e3fa682-cd99-43b4-9991-9400807b79a7/1337641):

> All hotels can arrange SPU protection. It costs about US$20 per day for a soldier, plus food.

Answer (score 6):

As of my personal experience from 2014, you have to request it. You will not automatically be accompanied by a police escort.

*** Update***

Again, as of my personal experience from 2014, you are able to travel to Tog Wajaale and Berbara without SUP facing no problems.